# Linux, Can't Start My Java Program After Restart

Tags: java, python, linux, service

I have a website which contains a button, when button is clicked, a .py file starts and runs my java based program.(I have a service on the background by the way) However when I restart, my service keeps running but my java based program doesnt triggered. Here's my server.py file's java program calling part :

```
def message_received(client, server, message):
if message=='<SYN>':
    server.send_message(client,"<ACK>")
    return

f.write('\"/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java\" -cp  \"eSign.jar:sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar\"ClientService_Data/' + guid_for_client + '.ini')
```

And here's my service in /lib/systemd/system :

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python  /home/ugurcan/Desktop/Linux_sign_test/server.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to start my java based program after I restart the computer without writing any code, thank you !!!

Comment: Your service is only for the server.py, right? And the server don't start automatically the java (only when button is clicked). So, on machine restart, nothing is starting the java. If i you want the java starting on machine restart, someone need to start it (you can create a service for java, or make a click on your server.py).

Comment: Thank you @Rafael !! , Now I'm going to add a service for java as you said and I'm gonna try it again